# Performance of using lambda function in template?

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

For example, I have a function template

```
template<class Fun>
void Foo(Fun f)
{
   ...
}
```

And the argument is a function object or a function pointer. If it is a normal function pointer, the performance is not good since the function cannot be inline. How about using a lambda function here? Thanks.

Comment: Like most things, if you haven't profiled that this is going to be a bottleneck, chances are it won't change a thing.

Comment: Lambdas should be as easy to inline as function objects. Whether they actually are is up to your compiler.

Comment: @DavidBrown: Indeed; lambdas *are* function objects.

Comment: If the argument is a function pointer, there is nothing fundamental stopping the compiler from eliminating the function call by inlining `Foo`.  It would have to notice that the function pointer variable was initialized at line X with function Y, no chance occurred for it to be modified before it was called on line Z, and replace the pointer access at Z with a direct call to Y.  It isn't completely trivial: once things become pointers, a compiler could just give up optimizing. And it is fragile: a seemingly innocuous operation could convince the compiler that the pointer could be modified.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you say, calls through function pointers often can't be inlined since the target function may only be known at run time.

A lambda can be inlined here. Its type (deduced as the template parameter `Fun`) is known at compile time; and therefore the function itself (`Fun::operator()`) is also known then.

Comment: Note that in some cases, stateful lambda's storing references may require pointer-based data access.  On the other hand, with the body of `Foo` visible as well as the body of `Fun`, the entire mess can be inlined and the lambda `Fun`'s existence removed.

Answer (score 3):

The closure type is the type created by a lambda expression. Its call operator (i.e., `operator ()`) is declared as `inline` as per 5.1.2/5 (emphasis is mine):

> > The closure type for a *lambda-expression* has a **public `inline` function call operator** (13.5.4) whose parameters and return type are described by the *lambda-expression*’s *parameter-declaration-clause* and *trailing-return-type* respectively.

In addition, the compiler can effectively see the definition of the call operator and, therefore, is able to inline the function call.

Comment: The `inline` keyword in C++ has nothing directly to do with making code `inline` in the sense of the optimization.

Comment: @Yakk: It's true that the compiler has no obligation to place the body of the function at the point of the call. However, the `inline` keyword indicates to the compiler that this is preferable (see 7.1.2/2).